# Page setup in rdlc files?

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have a .rdlc report file and I want to pre-set the paper size to A5 automatically in the report.

Comment: what exactly is your question? like how to set paper settings before printing?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Report Properties` and set the Page size As `Width:5.83in and Height:8.27in` the size of A5.